# How to detect when Angular has attached elements to the DOM?

Tags: angular

There is a component:

`<my-component></my-component>`

it's component receives a stream of numbers as `@Input`

`<my-component [data]="numbers$ | async"></my-component>`

inside the component we update the model:

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {

  numbers: number[] = [];

  @Input
  set data(numbers: number[]) {
      this.numbers = numbers;
  }

  constructor() {}

  myCallback() { }
}
```

then render the list of numbers, like this:

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="number of numbers">{{number}}</li>
</ul>
```

How to detect that `*ngFor` has rendered all elements? And how to invoke callback function `myCallback` after elements have been appended to the DOM?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ViewChildren` to get the QueryList of elements or directives from the view DOM. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent {

  numbers: number[] = [];
  @ViewChildren('li') elements: QueryList<any>;

  @Input() set data(numbers: number[]) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elements.changes.subscribe(li => {
      li.forEach(elm => this.myCallback(elm.nativeElement))
    })
  }

  myCallback(elm) {
    console.log(elm)
  }

}
```

template

```
<ul>
    <li #li *ngFor="let n of numbers">
        {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

> myCallback will log each elemnt but you still has access to all li elemnts

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhjv43)

[ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to emphasize that I need to detect a moment when angular has rendered elements to the DOM (after data emits). In your example we just call `myCallback` after numbers emitted, on this step `<li>` elements are not rendered yet. 

To be more specific I want to use `document.querySelector('')` to get access to the list items.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi I have update the answer by using `ViewChildren` decorator 

Answer (score 2):

You can create a directive to detect the elemntmrender to the dom and run a method at that time

```
import { Directive , Output ,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rendered]'
})
export class RenderedDirective {

   @Output() rendered:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.rendered.emit()
   }

}
```

> ngAfterViewInit will called after Angular has fully initialized a and render li elemnt

*MyComponent*

```
export class MyComponentComponent {

  numbers: number[] = [];

  @Input() set data(numbers: number[]) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
  }

  myCallback(elm) {
    console.log(elm)
  }

}
```

*template*

```
<ul>
    <li #li *ngFor="let n of numbers" (rendered)="myCallback(li)">
        {{n}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcni6y)

Answer (score 1):

this happens in NgInit

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

> ngOnInit()
>   Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.
>
> Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

Update:

I have propably misunderstood your question. You dont have any update on the ngFor. What is your usecase? Maybe there are different solutions for this.

Comment: correct by the data are async could become after the component is render check the console in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9v5dj

Comment: @malbarmawi nice  solution, but there is a callback for data, not for render. Or isn't it?

Comment: `ngOnInit` called only once after the first `ngOnChanges`. I need to call `myCallback` function on each `numbers$.next([1,2,3])`, but right after these elements rendered to the DOM.

Comment: @Fribu-SmartSolutions correct the first solution will not work , that why I use `ViewChildren` decorator