# How can I know when Angular App is fully rendered and DOM elements are generated?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular application, and an external library needs to match the DOM elements generated by Angular to inject some ads.

Is there any way I can know when Angular finishes the rendering and write to DOM? I tried `AfterViewInit` and `AfterViewCheck`, but it seems not for that purpose.

Comment: check may answer about the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376716/how-to-detect-when-angular-has-attached-elements-to-the-dom/55377054#55377054