# Angular5 call a function when html creates the button

Tags: html, angular, button, disable

Is it possible to call a function when the button is created.
So that I check in the function if a button has to be disabled or not

thx a lot!

Comment: `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` are made for that.

Comment: You might create a component for the button (the type of button) and might do some checkings on `ngOnInit`

Comment: If you wrap your button in a custom component you can use ngOnInit. Otherwise you can write a directive for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive to detect if element has created snd then run a function base on that

```
import { Directive , Output ,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[created]'
})
export class CreatedDirective {

     @Output() created:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.created.emit()
   }

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7uffsm)

> Another method by using **ViewChildren** or **ViewChild** check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376716/how-to-detect-when-angular-has-attached-elements-to-the-dom/55407782#55407782)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `@ViewChild()` and check the value to see if the button exists.

Something like:

In template:

```
<input type='button' #button />
```

In component:

```
@ViewChild('button') someButton;
```

In function:

```
if (this.someButton){
 // do something with someButton
 // You might want to do this.someButton.nativeElement and convert to HTMLelement to get the element as button
}
```